# Angular Table : Rows empty when I put ng if

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-ng-if, mat-table

I created an Angular MatTable with condition on the column like this :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="DateEntree">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date d'entrée </th>
    <ng-container mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <td
            *ngIf="element.DureeContrat && element.DateFinContrat && element.DateEntree && element.LieuUtilisation && element.DateSignatureIrrijardin && element.NumContrat && element.PrestataireLocation && element.TypeEngin && element.DateSignaturePrestataire && element.DateCirculation && element.PrixLoyer && element.DateSortie">
            {{element.DateEntree | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

But it show empty rows which, i supposed, are the data which dosnt respect the condition, I don't know how to remove the empty rows.

Here is a screenshot with the table :
As you can see there are 2 empty rows, below and above "99999"
[image: empty rows table]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please try by putting *ngIf on ng-container?

Comment: I can't put *ngIf on ng-container because there is already *matcellDef

Comment: Can you please try [class.hidden]="condition"? Refer screenshot: https://prnt.sc/tb6n2y

Comment: I can't put my condition because i can't take the data from "let element" for the condition

Answer (score 0):

```
 *ngIf="element.DureeContrat && element.DateFinContrat &&
 element.DateEntree && element.LieuUtilisation && 
 element.DateSignatureIrrijardin && element.NumContrat && 
 element.PrestataireLocation && element.TypeEngin && 
 element.DateSignaturePrestataire && element.DateCirculation && 
 element.PrixLoyer && element.DateSortie; then thenBlock; else 
 elseBlock"
```

Try this code.